# Why is 翼をください translated as "Please give me wings"?

Tags: translation

I checked that sentence on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&ei=LRv9WuvgJIK60AT3oYHgDg&q=%E7%BF%BC%E3%82%92%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%20translatio%20please&oq=%E7%BF%BC%E3%82%92%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%20translatio%20please&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6840.17699.0.17848.18.15.2.0.0.0.156.1430.5j8.13.0....0...1c.1j4.64.psy-ab..3.10.886...0i30k1j33i160k1j35i39k1j0i13i30k1.0.2XrT_BH_Yj4). Apparently, the translation is "Please give me wings." This confuses me because ...

翼 = wing 
を = direct object marker. 
ください = please

There's no give!

**Update**: this comes from the title of a [song](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%E7%BF%BC%E3%82%92%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%80%80tsubasa-wo-kudasai-give-me-wings.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Believing that 「ください」 always means "please" is a very common rookie mistake.

「ください」 can mean "please" ***only*** when it is attached ***as a subsidiary verb*** to another verb.  The other verb is the main verb.

「来{き}てください。」 (来る + ください) means "Please come (here)!"

「ちょっと待{ま}ってください。」 (待つ + ください) means "Please wait a sec!"

When 「ください」 is used independently (without being attached to another verb), it can ***only*** mean "***Give me ~~!***" or "***Please give me ~~!***"

Thus, 「翼をください」 means "(Please) give me wings!"

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is, ください is the shorter form of くださいませ which comes from くださる which is the polite version of くれる.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly did you see this sentence? It would be helpful if you gave the full context, otherwise, I would translate 「翼をください」the same way.

For example, when ordering food in a restaurant, saying 「お水【みず】をください」is understood to mean "Please give me water.", despite its literal translation being closer to just "Give water." (Unlike replacing 「ください」with 「お願【ねが】いします」-- in the latter case, it would mean "please do".)

EDIT: This question had no answers when I was typing this, so I didn't see Breton Loic's response. They also gave a good explanation for the hidden "give" in 「ください」.

EDIT #2: Edited per l'électeur's answer. 「ください」does not actually translate to "please", but is just a polite form of asking for something to be given to you.

Comment: From this song: https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%E7%BF%BC%E3%82%92%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%80%80tsubasa-wo-kudasai-give-me-wings.html

Comment: @alex Thank you for supplying the source. In this case, as I have amended my comment (and per l'électeur's comment -- never thought it was important to emphasise that 「ください」is not literally "please", and just contextually means that in this case), the intended meaning is most likely "Give me wings", as written in the site you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

It's already been answered but I want to add that ください is the polite form of くれ which is the command/imperative form of くれる which is to give (from the speaker's point of view).

Now, you can technically say for example 「水{みず}をくれ！」but that would be rather rude/abrasive.